# dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0040' near line 0: newline in field name '#padding'

Tags: dpkg

I am getting this `dkpg` error when I try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Unable to find a workaround.

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Review the contents of `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0040`

Comment: Probably easier to delete the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File sounds corrupted run

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0040
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

You can remove any other corrupted files in `/var/lib/dpkg/updates/` if needed and re-run those commands.

Post any additional errors you may have